# Upgrade from latest version

Tags: opensuse, dist-upgrade

Let me first apologize if the question itself is… stupid. Can I upgrade from a latest version, in this case openSuse LEAP 15.5? How problematic it would be, or which would be the consequences?

I thought in doing it because of a broken system that I do not know yet how to fix.

Thanks, in advance, and bests.

Comment: "upgrade from a latest version" to what? by definition you have "the latest version" and there wouldn't be an "upgrade", because then the "upgrade" would be the "latest version" and therefore you wouldn't have "the latest version" :p

Comment: Do you mean to revert to a previous stable version ?

Comment: Nope, to the same one… a kind of setting up the system again… Thanks.